# How to get the attribute value from xpath in dart?

Tags: xml, dart, xpath, attributes

I try to get the attribute value from xpath with this:

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:xml/xpath.dart';

final bookshelfXml = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document id="doc1">
<line id="1">
<data id="D1" value="20" />

<data id="D2" value="40" />
</line>
<line id="2">
<data id="D1" value="90" />

<data id="D2" value="340" />
</line>
</document>''';

final nn=[];
final document = XmlDocument.parse(bookshelfXml);
void main (List<String> arguments) {
  final document = XmlDocument.parse(bookshelfXml);
  final nodes = document.xpath('/document/line[@id="1"]/*/@id');
 
  for (final node in nodes) {
    nn.add(node);
  }
  for (var i=0; i<nn.length; i++) {
    print('id${i+1} is ${nn[i]}');
  }
}
```

The expectation here is

```
id1 is D1
id2 is D2
```

but I got

```
id1 is id="D1"
id2 is id="D2"
```

I need the solution which help me extract attribute's value (D1, D2) only not the value with the attribute name (id="D1", id="D2").

Comment: Can you not use `node['id']` to only select the id inside the for loop?

Comment: @ TijnvdEijnde, The id is attribute of the Data. I am trying to print out the value of this attribute in for loop.

Comment: I understand, I was thinking about this: `for (final node in nodes) { nn.add(node['id']); }` that way you will only save the value inside the `nn` List.

Comment: Could you use `node.value`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opted in my comment:

you can use `node.value` like this:

```
for (final node in nodes) {
    nn.add(node.value);
}
```